# como componetizar um fieldset com 2 temas de cor?

Tags: angular, formulário, campos

No angular  eu tenho esse codigo abaixo

```
<fieldset id="fieldset" class="blue-light>
      <legend>Informaçoes X</legend>

      Texto texto texto

    </fieldset>
```

eu tenho esse cod acima para fieldset azul e esse abaixo para fieldset padrão branco

```
<fieldset id="fieldset" class="light>
      <legend>Informaçoes X</legend>

      Texto texto texto

    </fieldset>
```

Gostaria de componetizar para que eu pudesse usar nas outras páginas, sem a necessidade de repetir scss, ou seja, fazer um unico scss e definir dois temas, branco e azul, é possivel? podem me ajudar?

é possivel inserir o legend dentro dele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta colocar o template do componente da seguinte forma:

```
<fieldset id="fieldset" [class]="tema">
      <legend>Informaçoes X</legend>

      Texto texto texto

    </fieldset>
```

O arquivo TypeScript do componente deve receber um `@input` e ficaria com algo parecido com:

```
@Input() tema;
```

E ao chamar o template do component que você criou, seria algo do tipo:

```
<componente-tema [tema]="blue-light"></componente-tema>
```

Acho que isso vai te atender.

---

[Projeto com exemplo](https://github.com/LucasAyrosa/StackOverflowAnswers/tree/master/SOpt366528)

Uma observação: eu fiz a escolha de escrever os estilos no arquivo CSS atrelado ao componente (`fieldset.component.css`), mas nada impede do estilo estar em outro arquivo, como por exemplo o arquivo geral de estilos do projeto (`app.component.css`) e ser importado na propriedade `styleUrls` do componente que irá utilizar, no caso o componente `fieldset.component.ts`.
Caso o estilo seja global, ou seja, vários componentes irão usar, o correto seria escrever eles no arquivo CSS geral mesmo e importar em quem precisar.

Comment: Oi Lucas, tudo bom? obrigada por responder. No caso ao chamar o componente no Template, o ts fica vazio mesmo? Sou nova em componetização

Comment: A princípio o TS é responsável pelo comportamento do template que ele está associado. Vou fazer um código em angular mais completo e disponibilizar na resposta pra ver se o entendimento fica melhor.